# Trying to create a simple slideshow with javaScript but images are not changing

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, slideshow

```
var getImage = document.getElementById("BCimage");
var imgArray = ["images/1.png","images/2.png","images/3.png","images/4.png"];
var countIndex=0;
function img(){
getImage.setAttribute("src", imgArray[countIndex]);
countIndex++;
if(countIndex>=imgArray.length){
countIndex=0;
}
}
setInterval(img, 5000);
```

Above is my simple js code to change images after every 5 sec. But the images are not shifting. Below is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="h"><a href="">hi</a></h1>
<div id="divs">
<img alt="image" src="images/1.png" id="BCimage">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="EventsJs.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be working, and it's working on my comp. Did you try to empty your cache? Else you can try to load all the images first (thanks to several ) and instead of changing the src of the image, changing the css style to display:block (show) or to display:none (hide)

Comment: I just tested also and it's working correctly for me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGmGxx are all the images the same? if they are you will most likely not see the change. Also is the JS file correctly referenced in your html? I can't see any reference to it?

Comment: Ya! all images are different and here,"<script type="text/javascript" src="EventsJs.js"></script>" you can see the reference to js in html code. Don't know guys why it isn't working. I'll give it another try later today ;). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check This link its running Example in JSFiddle and try to give us your html related problem in JSFiddle, 
Thanks

```
var getImage = document.getElementById("BCimage");
var imgArray = ["http://www.si.edu/Content/img/Home/youtube-40x40.png",
                "http://www.veryicon.com/icon/256/Emoticon/Black%20Power%20Emoticons/cry%20512x512.png",
 "http://www.trynova.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/rss-logo-40x40.png"
 ,
 "https://www.teleste.com/sites/default/files/media/fb_icon_40x40.png"];
var countIndex=0;
function img(){
getImage.setAttribute("src", imgArray[countIndex]);
countIndex++;
if(countIndex>=imgArray.length){
countIndex=0;
}
}
setInterval(img, 5000);
```

[Click here to See Your Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xqdv1gzw/9/)

i put online images in Your example for your understanding.

Comment: thanks! buddy. I'll find why it isn't working for me.

Comment: I think you dont have the JS file in your directory try to download that js file and mention in ur src which is in **<script type="text/javascript" src="EventsJs.js"></script>
**
**EventJs.js**

Comment: Hi! buddy. Some unwanted code was causing that issue. Now i have it resolved.